# InMemoryConnection for unit-testing Elasticsearch projects

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-net

Is it a good practice to use the `InMemoryConnection` class for unit-testing our Elasticsearch projects?

This class is being used in the actual source code for unit-testing. But the reason I am asking is because it derives from `HttpConnection` I am not quite sure if it opens any HTTP connection. Our unit tests go to a build server so I would like to avoid that. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If you look at the implementation of `InMemoryConnection`, you'll see that it overrides [DoSynchronousRequest](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Connection/InMemoryConnection.cs#L39) and [DoAsyncRequest](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Connection/InMemoryConnection.cs#L62) (the methdods of `HttpConnection` that are responsible for actually executing the HTTP request), and simply returns a fake `ElasticsearchResponse`.  No HTTP connections are open and no requests are made, so you are safe to use it in your unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

There is however a NuGet package for real integration tests from c#:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/elasticsearch-inside/

(I'm the author)

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for, but it won't work with dotnet core.

Comment: @kiml42 take a look at the Tests project within NEST that downloads and spins up different Elasticsearch cluster versions for integration tests - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/tree/2.x/src/Tests. Specifically, take a look at `ClusterBase` and `ElasticsearchNode` within the integration directory -https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/tree/2.x/src/Tests/Framework/Integration. These work on dotnet core as well as desktop CLR